# Your regular expression does not match the subject string

Tags: javascript, regex

I´m using regEx and this pattern is false.
It look like a \ is missing.
But where?

```
/^[^\.\:\;\§\ß\°\`\´\<\>\,\€\@\ä\ü\ö\Ü\Ä\Ö]+[A-Za-z0-9][\.\^\+\-\*\/\?\=\~\#\'\|]{0,1}+[^\.]+@^[\w]+[^\^\.\:\;\§\ß\°\\\`\´\<\>\,\€\@\ä\ü\ö\Ü\Ä\Ö]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,10}/
```

Please help me.

Comment: I'd look at `{0,1}+`

Comment: Why all these escapes?

Comment: I used an online regex tester and it said that I need all this \.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran it through online JS regex tester (I strongly suggest you try that in the future) and got the following errors here [.^+**-***/?=~#'|]{0,1}**+**

```
- Character range is out of order
+ The preceding token is not quantifiable
```

If you escape the `-` and remove the `+` you get a valid expression:

```
(^[^.:;§ß°`´<>,€@äüöÜÄÖ]+[A-Za-z0-9][.^+\-*/?=~#'|]{0,1}[^.]+@^[\w]+[^^.:;§ß°\`´<>,€@äüöÜÄÖ]+.[A-Za-z]{2,10}){6,998}
```

Can't guarantee if it's valid for your search, since you were only concerned about syntax, not meaning.